# My pc starts once in 10 and only on the bios

Tags: boot, cpu, bios, gpu

Recently my pc starts once in 10.

When it starts I only have access to the bios.

Here is a screensot of my bios as well as the components of my pc:

[image: bios]

[image: components]

Do you have an idea of the problem or a hint?

Comment: What is your power supply?  especially how many watts is it?

Comment: *When it starts I only have access to the bios.* It's UEFI actually but it doesn't matter in this situation. First things first check the boot order and adjust if necessary. If correct then you should check the health of the drive where the OS is installed.